# how to change position asterisk from right to left angular material 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

When I use input required field the asterisk default on right side I want to change it to left side If it possible.
thanks.

Comment: Please add more details, at least add minimal code to debug your problem. It is unclear what you are asking at that point.

Comment: thanks for answer.
for example this is default when I use 

 <mat-form-field style="    width: 100%;">
              <input [(ngModel)]="this.registerPageModel.userName" required matInput placeholder="Email">
            </mat-form-field>
but it's always show asterisk(star) right side. I want to show asterisk(star) left side.

Answer (score 3):

You can but not "properly" ... 
the asterisk is in span with class `mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c3-0 ng-star-inserted`

You can add `float:left` in your own css to change it to the left !

Comment: thank you for answer.
Can you show me for example css please.